# LibGDX WrappedText but by using colors within the text (java)

Tags: java, android, colors, libgdx, ansi-escape

I have made some code in the past to check through text to find color codes that will change the color of the text. Ex:

Drawing this:
`Hello my name&b is john`
would give this as a result when drawn: `Hello my name is john` but "is john" would be in blue since i used the &b color code. I am basically imitating ansi but for java.

Now I would like to wrap the text exactly like LibGDX's `BitMapFont.drawWrapped(...)` but still use the color codes. Anyone know how to do this? I would probobly be able to figure it out eventually but I just wanted to know if there was a better way than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is support for color markup: [Color Markup Language](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Color-Markup-Language):

> The BitmapFontCache class supports in-string colored text through a simple markup language.
>
> Markup is disabled by default. Use the method [BitmapFont.setMarkupEnabled()](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html#setMarkupEnabled-boolean-) to turn it on/off.
>
> The markup syntax is really simple but still versatile:
>
> - [name] Sets the color by name. There are a few predefined colors, see the Colors.reset() method for an exhaustive list. Users can define their own colors through the methods of the Colors class.
> - [#xxxxxxxx] Sets the color specified by the hex value xxxxxxxx in the form RRGGBBAA where AA is optional and defaults to 0xFF.
> - [] Sets the color to the previous color (kind of optional end tag)
> - [[ Escapes the left bracket.
>
> Notice that color names are case-sensitive, cannot be empty, cannot start with neither # nor [, and cannot contain ]. Also, any occurrence of [ in the color name must not be escaped.
>
> For a sample code see the test class [BitmapFontTest](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/BitmapFontTest.java).

Comment: wow thanks, instead of changing the color of the bitmap font, i have decided to just replace the color codes (&r, &b, etc) with the libgdx codes. Thanks a ton! Also can u change whether the text is bold or not?

Comment: Nevermind doesn't really, matter, i decided not to use this finally. I'm working on an mmo and if people write an invalid hex code in chat it will make everyones game crash. I think I had something good going before. Thanks anyways!